# Checkboxes: Selenium automation of a website with custom jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selenium, checkbox

I am using Selenium WebDriver with JavaScript to automate some testing of a website with a custom jquery plugin to make the forms all "pretty" called "jcf" - JavaScript Custom Forms https://www.psd2html.com/js-custom-forms/

I am attempting to write a method that will check to see if a checkbox is checked and then check or uncheck.

I have an xpath created leading to

I have tried:

```
if (element.isSelected){
    element.click
 }
```

And

```
boolean checked = button.getState();
if (button.getState()){
.click
```

All that happens is the button get clicked regardless of its state.

Is there another way to do this ? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Here is the DOM of the entire clickable box element containing one of the checkboxes

```
<li class="dashboard-product-list active" data-id="5" data-position="2"      data-has-batch="t" data-has-search-term-group="" data-has-shelf-page="">
    <input class="multi-product-list-checkbox checkbox jcf-hidden" type="checkbox"/>
    <span class="jcf-checkbox jcf-checked">
        <span/>
    </span>
    <span class="dashboard-product-list-info">
        <span class="product-list-name">Food 20</span>
        <span class="pl-details-ico pull-right has-tooltip-ico" data-pl-id="5" data-tooltip="View product list" data-hasqtip="2"/>
        <span class="product-list-retailer-name">Walmart.com</span>
    </span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned jQuery tag you can use following code to check whether checkbox checked or not:

```
 $("li.dashboard-product-list").each(function(){
    if($(this).find(".multi-product-list-checkbox").is(":checked")){
        //YOUR CODE GOES HERE
    }
});
```

Comment: But there are like 20 different checkboxes with that same class.  Won't that check the whole list ?   I specifically want this one "Food 20"

Comment: Where is your button? can you share button html as well?

Comment: Thats it.  That is the entire HTML for the element field with the button.  There are <li classes above and below that are just other fields with checkboxes.  The reason I was using <span class="jcf-checkbox jcf-checked"> (which works to clilck) is because  <input class="multi-product-list-checkbox checkbox jcf-hidden" type="checkbox"/> is Hidden

Comment: "Food 20" span is your button and click function on same should depend on checkbox isnt it?

Comment: The .click() function actually works on any of those spans.  Food 20 is just a text field next to the checkbox but the actual button itself according to chrome inspector is <span class="jcf-checkbox jcf-checked"> or <input class="multi-product-list-checkbox checkbox jcf-hidden" type="checkbox"/> which is hidden

Comment: As you mentioned you have multiple checkboxes with same class. You can loop through `li` and then check whether checkbox is checked or not. Find updated code snippet.